# what numbers should I use for Letter, Legal and A4?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need to print reports and I'm not able to fit the report in the page. I'm not sure about the units used. I know the default values are width 595 and height 842, but i don't know in what units are this magnitudes. Can someone help me on this or tell me what numbers should I use for Letter, Legal and A4 ??

Answer (score 4):

I've seen those units before in applications like Illustrator and they are in pixels or points. either one yields the same number as far as I've seen.

Letter: 612 pt x 792 pt (w x h)

Legal: 612 pt x 1008 pt

A4: 595.28 pt x 841.89 pt